# Css animation-fill-mode backwards does not work

Tags: html, css

I have a link that i want to animate his border from 1px to 5px on click and in the end of the animation i want the 1px to stay, i am using animation-fill-mode with backwards but i see that the 1px border does not apply after the animation is finish.

```js
document.querySelector('a').onclick = function() {

  this.classList.add('border-g');
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

body {
  margin: 100px;
}
a {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.border-g {
  -webkit-animation: border-grow 0.5s;
  animation: border-grow 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes border-grow {
  from {
    border: 1px solid #D74C43;
  }
  to {
    border: 5px solid #D74C43;
  }
}
@keyframes border-grow {
  from {
    border: 1px solid #D74C43;
  }
  to {
    border: 5px solid #D74C43;
  }
}
```

```html
<a>Hello world</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, you have to define the **final** state in your CSS first.

Then define the **new** start point in your animation

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}
a {
  border: 1px solid #D74C43;
  /* end like this */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-animation: border-grow 0.5s;
  animation: border-grow 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes border-grow {
  from {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    /* starts like this */
  }
  to {
    border: 5px solid #D74C43;
    /* animation ends then switches to final state */
  }
}
@keyframes border-grow {
  from {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
  to {
    border: 5px solid #D74C43;
  }
}
```

```html
<a>Hello world</a>
```

---

***EDIT***

To solve your **updated** question...the default states would need to be applied to the `border-g` class.

Otherwise the answer remains as previously.

```js
document.querySelector('a').onclick = function() {

  this.classList.add('border-g');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
a.border-g {
  border: 1px solid #D74C43;
  -webkit-animation: border-grow 0.5s;
  animation: border-grow 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes border-grow {
  from {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
  to {
    border: 5px solid #D74C43;
  }
}
@keyframes border-grow {
  from {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
  to {
    border: 5px solid #D74C43;
  }
}
```

```html
<a>Hello world</a>
```

Comment: But if i want the animation to add on click and the border to add only after click? thats why i started with transparent border. i am sorry for the misunderstood i will update the question.

Comment: That's another question. Clicks are handled by javascript.

Comment: Yes i know this is the same question look at the update please, thanks.

Comment: Please don't change the fundamental basis of questions once you have already received answers. It would be better to delete the question and ask a new one.

Comment: Updated answer now added.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read on [w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/#animation-fill-mode), in case of `animation-fill-mode: backwards`, the properties defined in the keyframe (`from` or `to`) will only apply to `animation-delay` period:

> 4.9. The animation-fill-mode property
>
> **backwards**
>
> During the **period defined by animation-delay**, the animation
>   will apply the property values defined in the keyframe that will start
>   the first iteration of the animation. These are either the values of
>   the from keyframe (when animation-direction is normal or alternate) or
>   those of the to keyframe (when animation-direction is reverse or
>   alternate-reverse).